# How to handle http requests to container

Tags: docker, centos

I have a centos7 server with docker installed. Currently i have 2 dockerised website in different containers, one (website1.com) listening on port 8081 and the other one (website2.com) on 8082. So port 80 of the server is not serving anything at them moment.

To access those websites i have to specify the right port number (e.g. website1.com:8081) so i want to accept any requests on port 80 and then serve the right website (e.g. website1.com should serve 0.0.0.0:8081)

How can i achieve that? And if possible, i need a solution that also offers a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a nginx (for example) reverse proxy on the host server or in a third container listening on port 80  ( see  proxy_pass directive ) , with 2 virtually host forwarding to the right container on 808x port .

here a sample: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/03/nginx-reverse-proxy-containerized-docker-applications/